# Can't resize picture on Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to add a picture to the body of an email. I insert it and then I try to drag the lower right corner to enlarge the image. When I end dragging, outlook restore the image to its original size.

Maybe the problem has to do with the fact that it is a very long image, although the size is as little as 1MB.

I already:

- Resized the image on an editor. When I insert the resized image to a new email it is shown with the same size as the non edited one.
- Checked that the DPI for the image is fine at 96.

Any idea of what could be happening?